# best configuration for large mysql database

Tags: mysql, server

I have the following scenario:

I need to update in a MySQL database ( innodb ) ~5-10 million records / day
For each record i update or insert i need to run ~10 read queries, then I split the record in ~4 tables.

Problem is right now I'm limited to ~3 million records / day, and i don't know what i should upgrade, CPU, ram or drives.

The server right now its an Intel E-2388G CPU @ 3.20GHz, 64GB ram, 2xNVME 1TB in raid 1.

I was thinking switching to a 128-256gb ram and 4xNVME TB in raid 10.

Entire scope of the server is to read data from text files and break them into various tables in a large database and at the end exporting an sql dump.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the physical size of the database? What's the physical size of a single row? What does "*Problem is right now I'm limited to ~3 million records / day*' actually mean?...why are you limited?

Comment: I'm limited because running those 3 million records update/instart will take me the entire 24hours, and i need to run more in 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

> i should upgrade, CPU, ram or drives?

No.  That might get you from 3M to 4M.  Then you will hit the same brick wall again, long before getting to 10M.  And there will be no further simple hardware fixes available.

Instead, let's see those dozen or so queries that go into each new item being received.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 4 tables.

Possible actions (but I need more details before elaborating):

- Batching arrivals -- Do the 5-10M rows come in one at a time or in clumps?
- Batch processing -- Depending on the details gathering 100 rows before starting to do the inserts may give you 10x speedup.  (Possibly acguevubg 30M/day?)
- Multi-threading -- Some designs are helped by having multiple clients inserting; some are hurt.  What do you have?
- 4 tables -- Maybe that needs pondering.
- Disk footprint, RAM size, buffer_pool size -- Are you I/O-bound or CPU-bound?  More RAM won't help if the buffer_pool is already bigger than it.  RAID won't help if the CPU or thread-contention or network bandwidth is the real bottleneck.  I can't judge the SSD you have, because specs don't always match real-life usage.  RAID puts a burden on the OS unless it is done in a hardware controller.
- Do you need all the data? -- In some apps, it is better to summarize the data as it comes in, then toss the "raw" data.  (Or keep the original log files that the data comes from -- and not INSERT the raw data.)
- "Exporting an SQL dump" -- how often? why?  Is it the raw data or normalized, etc, data?
- Also, for the list of options -- sharding.  (But this does not seem likely.)
- "update or insert" -- and a SELECT to decide between them?  Well IODKU (upsert) gives you an immediate 2x speedup, plus shorter code.
- "data from text files" -- CSV files?  If so, are you using `LOAD DATA`?  If not how do you parse the text files?